# Increment javascript variable function onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

This the page I'm working on:
http://gacc.nifc.gov/gbcc/predictive/PSA_ERCmap/Dev/PSAERCmap1.html

When you click on a shaded area the chart associated with the area pops up. What I'm trying to figure out is how to get the "Next PSA" link at the bottom to advance the chart in the popup to the next PSA every time you click it. I've figured out how to get it to advance by one PSA, but can't get it past that one. You'll see if you click on the link.

I have a function (called replace) that replaces the image source for the chart with a link to the next PSA number up. However, I can't figure out how to get it to increment. I tried PSA++ and PSA=PSA1 but neither of them work.

Here's my code:

```
<title>DEV PSA ERC Map DEV</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function overlay(a) {

            PSA = a.id;
            var numeric = a.id.replace('GB', '');
            PSAnum = Number(numeric)
            PSA1 = PSAnum + 1;
            nextPSA = ('0' + PSA1).slice(-2);
            var overlayContent = '';
            overlayContent += '<div id="overlay">';
            overlayContent += '<div>';
            var imgsrce = '';
            imgsrce += 'Charts/WebCharts/GB';
            imgsrce += numeric;
            imgsrce += '/ERCGraph.PNG';
            overlayContent += '<img id="chartimage" src="';
            overlayContent += imgsrce;
            overlayContent += '" />';

            overlayContent += '<br /><b><h1> <a href="#"     onclick="closePopup()">Close</a></b></h1>';
            overlayContent += '<b><h1>  <a href="#" onclick="replace(this)">Next PSA</a></b></h1>';
            overlayContent += '</div>';
            overlayContent += '</div>';
            $("#overlay").replaceWith(overlayContent);
            el = document.getElementById("overlay");
            el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
            if (el.style.visibility == "visible") {
                //el.style.visibility="hidden";
            }

        } //end of overlay function

    function replace(a) {

            image = document.getElementById('chartimage');
            console.log(image.src);
            console.log(PSA);
            image.src = 'Charts/WebCharts/GB';
            image.src += nextPSA;
            image.src += '/ERCGraph.PNG';
            PSA++;
            console.log(PSA);


        } //end of replace function

    $('.overlay-bg').click(function() {
        closePopup();
    });

    function closePopup() {
        el = document.getElementById("overlay");
        el.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    $(function() {
        $.get("getDate.php", function(data) {
            document.getElementById("timestamp").innerHTML = "<b>RAWS observations updated on " + data + "</b>";
        });
    });


    var file;
    file = 'GB_PSAdata_Real.js';

    $.getJSON(file, function(events) {
        var gbname = Object.keys(events);
        var divContent = '';
        divContent += '<div id="map">';
        divContent += '<map name="mapmap">';
        for (i = 0; i < gbname.length; i++) {
            var PSA = (gbname[i]);
            JSONcoords = events[PSA][0].Coords;
            JSONcoordString = JSONcoords.toString();
            divContent += '<area id="' + PSA + '" href="#" shape="poly" coords="';
            divContent += JSONcoordString;
            divContent += '" onclick="overlay(this)">';

            //      console.log(divContent)
        }
        divContent += '</map>';
        divContent += '<img src="GetPSAavg.php" width="826" height="1005" usemap="#mapmap" />';
        divContent += '</div>';
        $("#map").replaceWith(divContent);


        //$("#overlay").replaceWith(overlayContent);
        ;
    })
</script>





</head>

<div id="overlay">

</div>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <img src="PSlogo.png" style="height:75px">
        <img src="GBlogo.png" style="height:75px">
        <span><b>Great Basin ERC Percentiles</b> *Experimental*</span>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id="timestamp">RAWS Observations Updated</div>
        <div id="legend">
            <img src="LegendFull2.png" id="legendIMG">
        </div>


    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Instead of getting «a» from replace(this) on next, try keeping in a global variable which overlay is selected. And on previous/next de/increment this variable. I think you're not too far from a solution. When I click Next, «a» is empty and it load the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the code that increments the number into the `replace()` function, so it gets executed each time `replace()` is called. Currently it is executed only once when the `overlay()` function is called.

---

First, explicitly declare a global variable (outside of any function):

```
var currentPSANum = null;
```

Place this line inside the `overlay()` function:

```
currentPSANum = Number(a.id.replace('GB',''));
```

Then use the following for the `replace()` function:

```
function replace(a) {
    currentPSANum++;

    var image = document.getElementById('chartimage');

    image.src = 'Charts/WebCharts/GB' + ('0' + currentPSANum).slice(-2) + '/ERCGraph.PNG';
}
```

Comment: Right now at the end of the replace() function I have PSA++, so the incrementing is in the replace() function, right?

Comment: @NanetteHosenfeld - But you don't use `PSA` inside the `replace()` function. You use `nextPSA`, and that is set only in `overlay()`.

Comment: @NanetteHosenfeld - I have added to my answer with code that I think will work.

Comment: John, you are AMAZING. Thank you a million times! This is my first time asking a question, so as soon as I  can figure out how to accept your response as my answer, I'll do so. Thank you!!

Comment: @NanetteHosenfeld - I posted some cleaner code in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zpk5taex/). It doesn't run, but I didn't want to post the code in my answer. You could benefit from adding functions like the `getImageSrc()` function to eliminate duplicated code.

Comment: That looks so much cleaner! I'll definitely update my code with your suggestions.